# Google App Engine getJDOExceptionForNucleusException Error When Querying Database

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database, nosql

I am working on a project where Google App Engine is hosting the back-end datastore and I am able to send JSON requests to hit it via my site.

I have multiple tables (IE Order information, coupons, etc) and just made a new table, Session. The idea is, rather than using the Memcache to hold the data, I want the database to store the session IDs instead. I wrote the code to check against it, but whenever I search the database for the session ID, it returns an error:

```
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper getJDOExceptionForNucleusException: Exception thrown
Received a request to find an object of kind Session but the provided identifier is the String representation of a Key for kind Token
```

Here is a picture of what my database table looks like for this session I am referring to:
[image]

The issue I am confused about it is why would this be an issue, when other queries I do to the DB using a String as the primary key work just fine... Anyone have any ideas?

Full error output:

```
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper getJDOExceptionForNucleusException: Exception thrown
Received a request to find an object of kind Session but the provided identifier is the String representation of a Key for kind Token
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusFatalUserException: Received a request to find an object of kind Session but the provided identifier is the String representation of a Key for kind Token
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.stringToInternalKey(EntityUtils.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.idToInternalKey(EntityUtils.java:218)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.idToInternalKey(EntityUtils.java:208)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreIdentityKeyTranslator.getKey(DatastoreIdentityKeyTranslator.java:32)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.newObjectId(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3443)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.newObjectIdInstance(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1618)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1740)
    at com.package.core.DataSourceMgr.getObjectById(DataSourceMgr.java:118)
    at com.package.service.SessionService.getSession(SessionService.java:39)
    at com.package.misc.TESTQueryDBForSessionID.execute(TESTQueryDBForSessionID.java:25)
    at com.package.batch.CronShell.doGet(CronShell.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.package.core.DataSourceFilter.doFilter(DataSourceFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:482)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the issue was two-fold.

First off, the system was having a problem with me using a String as the primary key (No clue why this one was an issue while others were no issue...). Switched it to a long that was randomly generated.

That solved the first problem, but then a second one came up, when you have a long as the primary key / ID of the GAE Datastore, you cannot query it. You MUST use a Long (boxed version, capital L) instead of a long for it to work. After that, was able to delete existing items in the datastore and upload the new code.

tl;dr -- If anyone ever comes across this again, just make sure that:
1) You are using some type of Long to serve as the ID / Primary key
2) You are using a Long (not long) in your code:

```
public class Session extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    //...
}
```

-Pat